How to make a SliverList a DragTarget in Flutter
I have a CustomScrollView with multiple SliverList widgets, and I want each SliverList to act as a DragTarget. How can I make these lists accept drag-and-drop functionality? Here's a simplified version of my code where I attempt to wrap each SliverList in a DragTarget, but I need guidance on making it work correctly.
What I need help with:

How can I make each SliverList behave as a DragTarget and accept dragged items?
Is there anything I'm missing to implement this functionality correctly in a CustomScrollView?


Code sample
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    // ...
    SliverList.builder(...),

    DragTarget<String>(
      builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
        return SliverList.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(items[index].name); // Wrapping this widget with DragTarget works, but it's not the desired behavior
          },
        );
      },
    ),

    SliverList.builder(...),
    // ...
  ],
)

